# How to identify the reason behind certificate unknown error

Tags: ssl, curl, jetty, client-certificates, self-signed

I'm using `jetty v9.4.9`. I want to authenticate the requests using `client certificate`. I have configured `keystore` file in `'jetty-base\etc'`. I'm using `self-signed certificates` in both server and client.

I have a server certificate and root certificate. I have used OpenSSL to generate `keystore` file.

From https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/configuring-ssl.html,

Generating pkcs12 file:

```
$ cat example.crt intermediate.crt [intermediate2.crt] ... rootCA.crt > cert-chain.txt
$ openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey example.key -in cert-chain.txt -out example.pkcs12
```

Loading keystore file:

```
$ keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore jetty.pkcs12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore keystore
```

Using above methods, I have generatd `'new_keystore'` file. I have configured the newely generated keystore file in `jetty-base\start.d\ssl.ini` as

```
jetty.sslContext.keyStorePath=etc\new_keystore
jetty.sslContext.trustStorePath=etc\new_keystore
```

Now I'm sending request using `cURL` in `Windows`

Request:

```
curl -v --cacert root.crt --key client.key --cert client.crt https://localhost:8443
```

This results in `unknown certificate` error

```
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Request CERT (13):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS alert, certificate unknown (558):
* error:14094416:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert certificate unknown
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) error:14094416:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert certificate unknown
```

In `jetty`, how to identify the reason behind the `unknown certificate` error? Can it be configured to displayed on `log` file? How to debug and fix it?

Comment: Add `-Djavax.net.debug=all` to your java command line on the server side to see the debug of TLS/SSL on java.  Also, please edit your question and add the details on how you created your self-signed certificate, as that's very important to get absolutely correct.

Comment: Typically the server checks if the certificate presented was issued by a known authority. So if you are using a self signed certificate you will need to add it as a trusted authority, otherwise it will never validate.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt Please find my edit. I have got certificates from client and I'm not aware how it is being created.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Please find my edit. I'm new to it. I have added root cert and server cert in keystore file and given the same as trustStorepath. Do I need to add client cert?!

Comment: how the certificates themselves were created and stored in the keystore are also important. (the key algorithm for your private key and certificate shouldn't be any of the java banned algorithms.)